# Is $387420547$ another counter example to John H. Conway's Problem $5$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, prime-factorization, conjectures

John H. Conway is a mathematician who created these *five $\$1000$ problems*. They are just problems that he discovered himself and that relate to mathematics, mainly on a recreational level. Anyone to have "solved" one of the problems (by "solved", I mean provide a proof or counterexample, etc) will win $\$1000$, and will win that for every problem solved.

I looked at *Problem $5$* in particular, and someone had found a counterexample to the proposition and won the prize. You can go [here](https://oeis.org/A248380/a248380.pdf) to check out the problems, and Problem $5$ is the very last one.

It mentions that $20$ seems to (also) be a counterexample, but it has not been proven to be. However, I believe I might have found myself another potential counterexample, namely, $$387420547.$$ This number cannot be generated from any other numbers, as what can happen in Problem $5$. This is because in the problem, you can join primes together to make a new number that might be prime. In the number above, there are n prime numbers such that when you concatenate them, they make this number. After going to the link and reading the problem, you will understand why this is very important.

If you cannot access the link, please let me know, and I will write out the problem in this post for all to see. My question is, *Is the number above an actual counterexample? It seems like it never climbs to a prime, no matter how many iterations I make. Can it be checked for certain?*

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [prime factorization of $387420547$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+factorization+of+387420547) is $31\times101\times123737$, so concatenating them doesn't give you the original number $387420547$.

Comment: @Rahul but does the prime factorisation, when you join the primes together, do they form a prime number? According to my computer, they don't, and the prime factorisation of *that* doesn't form a prime number either, and so forth (apparently). Like $20$. The prime factorisation of $20$ is $2^2\times 5$ which makes $225\neq 20$. But $20$ never seems to climb to a prime

Comment: Could you clarify your assertion? Specifically, are you asserting that your number does not climb to a prime, and your evidence is that you have tried iterating the climb function a few times and it hasn't yet hit a prime?

Comment: @PatrickStevens yes that is correct. I will clarify that immediately. I tried iterating the climb function and eventually hit a number that was $50$ something digits, still not prime...

Comment: I see, I apparently misunderstood what you meant by the sentence "In the number above, there are n prime numbers such that when you concatenate them, they make this number." Given that we don't even know how to prove whether 20 is a counterexample, I'd say it could be pretty hard to prove whether 387420547 is a counterexample. If you find a number such that iterating the function gets you stuck in a finite cycle of nonprimes (for example, 13532385396179 gives a cycle of length 1), that would be another concrete counterexample.

Comment: @Rahul I just wanted to check to see how many iterations we can make without hitting a prime, but my computer isn't good enough. Sorry if you were misunderstood

Comment: I got as high as 3313235318982763712688623927562117071661346331635447203150653287317716067240517950521274673875873624320571948594688659440542373328510103819 before getting bored. I would suggest a fast factorization tool like https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM -- you should be able to get up to a few hundred digits.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg *alpetron*? What is that??

Comment: @user477343 Just an online tool that does efficient factorization of large integers. Nothing in particular, just one I found quickly on Google.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg and here I am writing a program....